# Vishay TVS diode identification

Tags: identification, tvs

I'm trying to identify a TVS diode.

It's from Vishay with the markings `200C 8CA`.

That's where I can't quite confirm what it is.

[image]  [image]

Comment: Areo, if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a bidirectional 200 volt TransZorb type 1.5SMC200A as per [this data sheet](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2045986.pdf): -

[image]

Of course you should check that it dimensionally matches the data sheet i.e. it's case size is "SMC".